# How to copy recursively but ignore gitignored files?

Tags: git, copy

I have a folder containing a bunch of git repositories. I would like to create a back up of this folder, but the problem is that if I just copy everything (recursively e.g. using `cp -r <folder>`) the resultant folder is huge. This is because each repo has git ignored files/folders that are large in size (e.g. virtual environments, data files) that I do not want to back up. All repos are small in size otherwise.

Is there a way to recursively copy a folder but only include non-gitignored files/folders? Ideally I'd like to include the `.git` folders to store all commit/branch history as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Backup != repo-copy. You have to select only one form
2. If you want backup(s) (snapshot of some tree without history), you have to read about [git archive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) and use it, for each git-repo separately
3. If you want "copy with history" just `git clone` each repo (and regularly `git pull` later)

Comment: Okay, but what if I want to copy a repo into a docker image when building it? But without the parts in .gitignore and I don't need the git history.

Comment: @grofte In your question you said you wanted `.git` as well but here you say that you don’t need the Git history?

Comment: Ah, no I meant whether I could use the `.gitignore` file when building a docker image. Instead of explicitly writing what to copy in the `dockerfile`. It's tangentially related because the original was asking for a bash command. But tbh it is probably better and safer to be explicit in the `dockerfile`.